# Conditional Expectation Given Sum of Dependent R.V.s

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-expectation

I want to find

$$
E[\Phi_1 | c_1 \Phi_1 + c_2 \Phi_2 + c_3\Phi_3 = x]
$$

as well as (if possible?)

$$
E[\alpha_1 \Phi_1 + \alpha_2\Phi_2 | c_1 \Phi_1 + c_2 \Phi_2 + c_3\Phi_3 = x]
$$

where $c_1, c_2, c_3, \alpha_1, \alpha_2$ are constants, given that:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}  \Phi_1 \\  \Phi_2 \\  \Phi_3  \end{bmatrix}
\sim \mathcal{N}\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_{11} &  \sigma_{12} &  \sigma_{13} \\
\sigma_{12} &  \sigma_{22} &  \sigma_{23} \\
\sigma_{13} &  \sigma_{23} &  \sigma_{33} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\right)
$$

---

Let $X = c_1 \Phi_1 + c_2 \Phi_2 + c_3\Phi_3$.  I have found that $E[X] = 0$ and $\text{var}[X] = c_1^2\sigma_1^2 + c_2^2 \sigma_2^2 + c_3^2 \sigma_3^2 + 2c_1c_2\sigma_{12} + 2c_1c_3\sigma_{13} + 2c_2c_3\sigma_{23}$, although I'm not sure these help me in any way.

I'm doing this for a research project I'm working on.  So much of the information out there seems to be on independent R.V.s.  Is there a typical pattern to follow in order to go about solving general problems like these?  Are there any specific references that I should look up?

Comment: I'm not sure what you have in mind by "general problems like these", but when you're dealing with multivariate normal distributions, the pattern is simple. First, linear combinations of multivariate normal vectors are multivariate normal, and second, the conditional expectation $E[X\mid Y]$ is just the regression line: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions.

Comment: Indeed, so all you need to compute each $$E(\Phi_i\mid c_1 \Phi_1 + c_2 \Phi_2 + c_3\Phi_3)$$ is the covariance matrix of the centered vector $$(\Phi_i,c_1 \Phi_1 + c_2 \Phi_2 + c_3\Phi_3)$$ This "linear" approach is quite specific to gaussian families.

Comment: @snarfblaat - I got lost at "$E[X|Y]$ is just the regression line," but I imagine that is related to the last few sentences of the section "Conditional distributions."
Thank you for your reply!

Comment: @Did - Are you saying to consider bivariate $Y = A\Phi$ with $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \end{bmatrix}$?  But how do I get correlation between $\Phi_1$ and $c_1\Phi_1 + c_2\Phi_2 + c_3\Phi_3$?  And thank you!

Comment: @Did - Wait--it's $A \Sigma A^T$ (where $\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix given in the question above)?  So I get $\Sigma^* = A\Sigma A^T = \begin{bmatrix} \sigma_{11} & c_1\sigma_{11} + c_2\sigma_{12} + c_3\sigma_{13} \\ c_1\sigma_{11} + c_2\sigma_{12} + c_3\sigma_{13} & c_1^2\sigma_1^2 + c_2^2 \sigma_2^2 + c_3^2 \sigma_3^2 + 2c_1c_2\sigma_{12} + 2c_1c_3\sigma_{13} + 2c_2c_3\sigma_{23} \end{bmatrix}
$.  Then I can follow the procedure under the "Conditional distributions" section mentioned in previous comment.  Thanks so much!